# Layer Problem After Build&Run

Tags: unity

I finished my game and it runs fine inside Unity. I exported it to WebGL and ran it there but the main menu background does not show. It looks the background color and is pretty annoying. Here are some snapshots:

[image]

It's supposed to look like this. It looks like this when I run in Unity.

But when I export the game, here is what I see:

[image]

Anyone know where should I look to fix this? Here are my player settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you forgot to show us how the background object is configured. Is it a UI image? A texured quad? A sprite renderer? etc...

Comment: I changed it to an Image and now it is working fine. Seems I have to use Image component to show something inside the canvas.

Comment: Want to share your solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I added an Image component to the GameObject that holds the sprite. Then I had to make that default sprite object transparent so that it wouldn't interfere with the actual sprite I wanted to show.

Comment: Why not delete the sprite renderer component and just use an Image component alone if you're intending to display this with the UI system?

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer "Accepted" if it worked for you.